# Optimize Bash Script for Self Linking Tweet

Tags: bash, optimization, twitter

I want to optimize this Bash script because the time it takes to load greatly effects the probability that it will be successful. Is there an optimizer out there for bash? Could you help me optimize this?

```
A="0"
B=0
C=0
D=0

until [ $SUCCESS -eq 1 ]; do
    TWEET=$(t update "This tweet is the best tweet https://twitter.com/notnowwww/status/$URL")
    num1=${TWEET[@]:51:18}
    if [ $URL -eq $num1 ]; then
        SUCCESS=1
        exit
    fi
    MIN=$(($num1-$num1save))
    echo $MIN
    URL=$(($num1+$MIN))
    yes | t delete status $num1
    num1save=${TWEET[@]:51:18}
done
```

The best optimization I have so far is

```
A="0";B=0;C=0;D=0;
until [ $B -eq 1 ]; do
    E=$(t update "This tweet is the best tweet https://twitter.com/notnowwww/status/$A");D=${E[@]:51:18}
    if [ $A -eq $D ]; then
        B=1;exit
    fi
    F=$(($D-$C));A=$(($D+$F));yes|t delete status $D;C=${E[@]:51:18}
done
```

I've even made a git for it. https://github.com/quitequinn/MetaTweet

Comment: I don't think variable name length has any significant impact on the speed of the script. Nor does replacing newlines with `;`.

Comment: The only potential optimization I can see is to use `num1save=$num1` instead of repeating the substring access.

Comment: Given that you exit as soon as you set `SUCCESS`/`B` to `1` there's no reason to test that in the while loop. So using `while :; then` or `while true; then` is likely a *slight* improvement. As is removing the assignment. Creating a static string of the correct amount of `y` values such that `echo "$ystring"` can be used in the place of `yes` might also help a tiny bit. That being said I think the network related actions of `t` are going to **wildly** dominate the runtime of this loop as compared to the actual script tasks.

Comment: I think this question is off-topic because it would be better asked on a site dedicated to code reviews, such as http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks so much Etan, but what do you mean by "Creating a static string of the correct amount of y values such that echo "$ystring" can be used in the place of yes"? Could you give me an example of that?

"network related actions of t" <- sigh... ya

Comment: All `yes` does is spit out a never-ending stream of `y\ny\ny\n...`. It dies when the pipe is killed because the consumer terminates. All you are doing is feeding `y` to the prompts from `t`. But the necessary number of `y`s needed is known ahead of time for this scenario. So just create a string of enough `y\n` repetitions to satisfy the prompts and stick that in a variable and then echo it out when necessary.

Comment: It may be entirely possible to optimize `t` for this usage though (but that's a different question).